# gurobipy.GurobiError: Second argument should be a list of Var

Tags: python, gurobi

The following error was encountered when using LinExpr in gurobi:

```
    contribution = LinExpr(coefficients, variables)
  File "src\gurobipy\linexpr.pxi", line 83, in gurobipy.LinExpr.__init__
gurobipy.GurobiError: Second argument should be a list of Var
```

And my code as follow:

```
from gurobipy import *


def process_group(item_values: list, m: Model, prefix: str):
    # Create one binary variable per item in the group.
    model = Model()
    shape = len(item_values)
    bns = model.addVars(shape, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=(prefix + "_choice"))

    # A constraint that ensures only 1 item in this set is chosen.
    model.addConstr(bns.sum() == 1, name=(prefix + "_choose1"))

    # contribution = x11 * b11 + x12 * b12 + ...
    coefficients = item_values
    variables = tuplelist(bns)
    print("coefficients:", coefficients)
    print("variables:", variables)
    contribution = LinExpr(coefficients, variables)
    return contribution


def main():
    # Data and parameters
    group_values_list = [[10, 20, 30], [20, 30], [10],
                         [10, 30], [10, 20, 30, 40],
                         [10, 20, 30]]
    max_total_value = 100
    for i, g in enumerate(group_values_list):
        print("i:", i)
        print("g:", g)

    # Model
    m = Model()
    contributions = [process_group(g, m, "set%d" % i)
                     for i, g in enumerate(group_values_list)]
    total_value = sum(contributions)

    # Limit the total value of the chosen items
    m.addConstr(total_value <= max_total_value,
                "total value limit")

    # Objective is to maximize the total value
    m.setObjective(total_value, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

    # Optimize model
    m.optimize()

    for v in m.getVars():
        print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

    print('Obj: %g' % m.objVal)

main()
```

The purpose of the code is to find out all the solutions which the elements of the solution must belong to the corresponding list.
How should I fix this error?

Comment: If Richard's answer resolved your problem, please make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create a `tuplelist` of a `list`. The function `addVars` returns a `list` of variables objects already. This means, you should be able to simply do:

```
contribution = LinExpr(coefficients, bns)
```